# theMovieDB api call throwing IOEXception

Tags: java, android, http, themoviedb-api

I am making an android app that uses theMovieDB API.
Look at the part of my class extending AsyncTask.

```
private HttpURLConnection urlconnection = null;
    private URL url;

    protected String doInBackground(String[] task)
    {
        String DATA=null;
        String baseAddress="https://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/";
        String apiKey="225b36fd29826b4c9821dd90bfc4e055";
        Uri Url = Uri.parse(baseAddress).buildUpon().appendEncodedPath(task[0]).appendQueryParameter("api_key",apiKey).build();
        Log.d("built URL",Url.toString());
        try
        {
            url= new URL(Url.toString());
            urlconnection= (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            urlconnection.setRequestMethod("GET");
            urlconnection.connect();

            InputStream inputStream = urlconnection.getInputStream();
            if (inputStream==null)
            {
                return null;
            }
            BufferedReader reader= new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
            StringBuffer buffer=null;
            String line;

            while ((line=reader.readLine())!=null)
            {
                buffer.append(line+'\n');
            }
            DATA=buffer.toString();

        }
```

I am getting IOException (seen in logcat). I checked the built URL on the browser(it was working). The Same set of syntax did work on openweather api. Is there any other thing that themovieDb API need? Help me Solve it. I did check there documentation but there was no info for android.

Comment: Post the exception you are getting.

Comment: @Januson Just this "E/cloudConnect: Error"

Comment: Can you paste what Log.d("built URL",Url.toString()); is printing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i got the Solution. I was connected to my mobile hotspot which due to some reason does not work as expected. Switching to my home WIFI fixed the issue. 
Thanks for giving your time on my question